# Iterate JSON to create navigation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

This is the JSON I have, I want to iterate by pageName to construct the navigation in li. I trying in react.

```
{
"pname": "Project Name",
"page1": [{
    "pageName": "Home",
    "content": "xyz"
}],

"page2": [{
    "pageName": "About Us",
    "content": "abc"
}]
}
```

import data from "./data/data";
Below code gives me pname, page1 and page2, instead I want page1 & page2 values and want to ignore pname.

```
return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
     {
      Object.keys(data).map((value, index) => {
        return (
           <li key={value} className="nav-item active">     
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">{value} <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li> 
        );
      })
      }
)     
      </ul>
```

My attempt 2, which returns error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

```
return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
     {
{
      Object.keys(data).map((value, index) => {
        return (
           <li key={value} className="nav-item active">     
               {value.pageName.map(function (component, i) { 
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">{value.pageName}</a>
              })}
           </li> 
        );
      })
      }
)     
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the current key holds an array, if it does then display it.

```
return (
  <ul className="navbar-nav">
    {Object.keys(data).map(
      (value, index) =>
        Array.isArray(data[value]) && (
          <li key={index} className="nav-item active">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
              {data[value][0].pageName}{" "}
              <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        )
    )}
  </ul>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script>

const data = {
  pname: "Project Name",
  page1: [
    {
      pageName: "Home",
      content: "xyz"
    }
  ],

  page2: [
    {
      pageName: "About Us",
      content: "abc"
    }
  ]
};
  
</script>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          {Object.keys(data).map(
            (value, index) =>
              Array.isArray(data[value]) && (
                <li key={index} className="nav-item active">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                    {data[value][0].pageName}{" "}
                    <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              )
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
     {
      Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].hasOwnProperty("pageName")).map((key, index) => {
        return (
           <li key={value} className="nav-item active">     
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">{data[key].pageName} <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li> 
        );
      })
      }
)     
      </ul>
```

Going through `pageName` doesn't require an iteration/map method, instead what you need to do is filter out keys that you don't want to pass to the map function

Comment: oh yeah, I was trying to check if the key had a property pageName, I've edited the answer now to check for a pageName key in the value

Comment: BTW, value will not work since you are iterating through the keys

Comment: Error says: 'key' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: edited again, can you check? I don't have a javascript editor handy to test the code

Answer (score 0):

filter by removing key "pname". you also have to read 0 index array value to access object with page name.

```
return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
     {
      Object.keys(data).filter(key=>key !== "pname").map((objKey, index) => {
        return (
           <li key={index} className="nav-item active">     
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">{data[objKey][0].pageName} <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li> 
        );
      })
      }
)     
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The first thing here is that you need to parse the json in order to get your object from it, so I would assume the name of your json object to be `jsonBody`

`const obj = JSON.parse(jsonBody)`

2. You can now work with the object. However, there is one more problem which can be solved in several ways but I would use one. => The `obj` object has several properties that you need and don't need, for e.g. you don't need the pname key. So what we can do in this case is to loop through the obj and get the properties that have values that are arrays and have the property `page`.

OR. you could use regex to check for keys that start with `page` and are followed by a `digit` (it all depends on what you expect the object to look like)

```
const navs = [];

Object.values(obj).forEach((content) => (Array.isArray(content) && content[0].pageName) ? navs.push(content[0].pageName) : '')
```

By the enf of this operation the navs array should contain your navigation items which you can iterate on in react to get your nav items.

NB: It is sometimes better to separate each concern so it's easier for others to onboard and wasy for you to undersatnd when next you come on the project.

If you however want the whole operation done in your component then you can do something like this:

```
return (
JSON.parse(jsonBody).map(content => {
  (Array.isArray(content)  && content[0].pageName) ? (
    <li key={content[0].pageName}>
       <a href='#'>{content[0].pageName}</a>
    </li>
   ) : ''
 } )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? (Filter out values which are not arrays, then use map).

```
return (
  <ul className="navbar-nav">
    {Object.keys(data)
      .filter(key => data[key] instanceof Array)
      .map(key => (
        <li key={key} className="nav-item active">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            {key} <span className="sr-only">{data[key][0].pageName}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Following is running example to see the output. In the code snippet I used as string literals map to see the output. Hope that make sense.

```js
const data = {
"pname": "Project Name",
"page1": [{
    "pageName": "Home",
    "content": "xyz"
}],

"page2": [{
    "pageName": "About Us",
    "content": "abc"
}]
}

      
const lis = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key] instanceof Array).map(key => (`<li key={${key}} className="nav-item active">     
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">{${key}} <span className="sr-only">{${data[key][0].pageName}}</span></a>
           </li>`));

console.log(lis)
```